# How to search NSArray in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

HI friends,
 I have an array consists of many names. I want to search the names starting from the character "c". How can I search the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* firstLetter;

for(NSString* currentString in yourArray)
{
     firstLetter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [currentString characterAtIndex:0]];
     if([firstLetter isEqualToString:@"c"])
     {
          // NAME OK
     }
     else
     {
         // NAME WRONG
     }
}
```

Comment: Why the %d?? Did you try this?

Comment: Oops that's a mistake ! Edited

Comment: This is very inefficient. It creates a new formatted string for each item in `yourArray` and performs a string comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is with `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`:

```
[yourArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id name,NSUInteger idx,BOOL *stop) {
    if ([name characterAtIndex:0] == 'c') {
          NSLog(@"Name begins with c: %@",name );
    }
}];
```

(and also note that you would want to test for 'C' in addition to 'c' if your input is not all lowercase)

Comment: +1. I'm interested why you chose a block enumeration rather than a for loop. Personal preference or a particular reason?

Comment: If you want to stop the search when you hit the first match, that's easier to do with a block (*stop = true) than with a straight `for ...in` fast enumeration. The block construct also makes it easier to parallelize the operation if desired (using the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option on `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]`).

Comment: It also gives easy access to the index of the object, which takes a bit more work when using fast enumeration.